# create field in mongodb by $gte and condition $cond

Tags: mongodb, if-statement, aggregation-framework, conditional-statements

I need to create a field on based on a condition in collection called locales:

if a place has more than 10 tables ("mesas_es"=10) the new field should be true, if the place has less than 10 tables ("mesas_es"=9)the new field should be false, the name of the new field is inspeccionar so far this is what I have get

```
db.locales.update({$and: [{desc_barrio_local: "GUINDALERA"},{desc_distrito_local:"SALAMANCA"},{desc_ubicacion_terraza: "Acera"}]},{$set: {inspeccionar: {$cond: {if: {$gte: ["mesas_es", 10]}, then: true, else: false}}}},{multi:true})
```

so far I only get a nested array containing the conditions

inspeccionar: Object
$cond: Object
if
:
Object
$gte
:
Array
then
:
true
else
:
false

Answer (score 1):

You need to [update the documents with the aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) as follows:

```
db.locales.updateMany(
    {
        desc_barrio_local: "GUINDALERA",
        desc_distrito_local:"SALAMANCA",
        desc_ubicacion_terraza: "Acera",  
    },
    [
        { $set: {
            inspeccionar: {
                $gte: ["$mesas_es", 10]
            }
        } }
    ]
);
```